# What is this black and white spider with a bowl/tube web in England?

Tags: safety, bugs, bug-identification, england, spider

I was walking my dog through high grass, in England. We came across a big spider. The web was almost like a bowl/tube. The spider was black but the back part was big and a white colour. We avoided that spider but we came across many more. I have looked them up but can't find a matching image or description.

Comment: There are way too many species of spider to make it possible to identify one from this kind of description.

Comment: Please note that the spider was identified by userX as a "false widow," after reading the information and seeing the picture in the answer by @Liam.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be two I'd guess:

### Labyrinth spider

It's hard to completly identify but by the sound of the web shape and your description it is most likely a Labyrinth spider

[image]

[More info here](http://www.uksafari.com/funnelwebs.htm)

> At this time of the year, the funnel webs in our gardens are normally
> the work of Labyrinth spiders.  Labyrinths are common, shy little
> critters, and being a dull grey-brown colour they go largely
> unnoticed.  It's only when they start building their webs that they
> draw attention to themselves.

They are very common and not remotely poisonous to humans,

### False Widow

The only poisonous spider (that I'm aware of) in the UK is the [false widow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-24636116). Your description of the spider itself does vaguely match this:

[image]

---

Neither are aggressive though the false widow is more dangerous (still very unlikely to cause serious damage unless you have a heart condition or something)

I'd be interested to know which if any it matches?

Comment: In fact. Looking at more images it wad a false widow. I saw quite a few which is scary