# What is the species of this spider? Is it venomous?

Tags: uk, bugs, spider, bug-identification

I found this tonight on the external wall:

[image]

Location: UK (south)

I have a feeling it is a young green fang spider, please correct me if I am wrong.

And the most important question: is it venomous?

Comment: There are practically no venomous spiders in the UK, the exception to this rule is the [false widow](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5785/2766). This is only dangerous if you have a pre-existing heart condition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That actually looks to be a Woodlouse Hunter *(Dysdera crocata)*. They prey exclusively on woodlice. They also go by a few other names such as: woodlouse spider, sowbug hunter, sowbug killer, pillbug hunter, and slater spider.

[image: Woodlouse Spiders]
Image source: http://www.whatsthatbug.com/category/spiders/sow-bug-killers/

From the Pennsylvania State Entomology Department site:

> *Dysdera crocata* is a hunting spider found from New England to Georgia and west to California. **It is also a commonly encountered spider in England**, northern Europe, and Australia. The woodlouse hunter preys on pill bugs or sow bugs (order Isopoda) and derives its common name from the British common name for these crustaceans. *D. crocata* is known to feed on other arthropods as well. This is the only species of the family Dysderidae known to occur in Pennsylvania.
>
> Source: http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/woodlouse-hunter

Important to your question of whether it is poisonous, also from the Pennsylvania State site:

> #### Medical Importance
>
> D. crocata bites have been implicated in causing a localized, intensely itching erythema 4 to 5 millimeters in diameter. The bites apparently do not result in any systemic neurotoxicity or cytotoxicity.

... which means that if you mishandle one and get bitten, you'll likely only experience a swelling or reddening of the skin that itches something fierce. The bites, although painful, and while some of their venom may get injected into you, are not poisonous to humans. At worst, one might experience an allergic reaction from a bite, similar to that of a mild bee sting.

Comment: color-wise far away, shape-wise very close, apart of the fangs. On the image you have uploaded they are closing into an almost circle shape, the spider I posted hasn't got such long fangs. ( Sorry for a bad shot :) )

Comment: @san.chez The chelicerae (and fangs) aren't fixed, and spiders can flex and move them in the process of cleaning, eating, and fighting. So it certainly seems that the one you took a picture of had them folded inward. These spiders are very common here in Colorado — just as they are in the UK — and I've come across them many times around the house and garden. Here's another picture to consider: http://media-3.web.britannica.com/eb-media/28/115528-004-9D907A00.jpg

Comment: What about the colour? It is different.

Comment: Slight variations in color are natural. It's basic color scheme is still that of a woodlouse hunter. For a more accurate color representation, you might've carefully put the spider in a glass jar, then take a picture of it under different lighting. Your camera could also have had its settings set to something less-than-ideal for insect photography.

Comment: This is very late, but I simply brightened the image using Paint, and the characteristic color pattern of Dysdera became visible.